# IdentityServer4 and Angular5 with Oidc-Client

Tags: identityserver4

I am using identityserver4 with aspnetIdentity for usermanagerment
the account controller from sample application is different that is from aspnetIdentity
now the Logout method that Oidc-client calls has logoutId
but as my controller is not having this How I can make it running
do I need to copy the account controller from the sample application?

Comment: can you show your client config ?

Comment: I have chnaged thesample code and do the fresh Identityserver installation and it start working